# Not getting the border at the bottom fit to textfield width

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield, border

Below is the image of the border at the bottom in UITextField.
But not getting fully underline the UITextField.
[image: Not fully underline the TextField]

Below is the code I am using.
    extension UITextField {

```
    func underlined(){
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(1.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

// call

```
yourTextField.underlined()
```

Comment: where you called this yourTextField.underlined() in viewdidload or else

Comment: yes, In viewdidload() function

Comment: try to put it in viewdidappear

Answer (score 2):

you are called the method before UI Updation, so call your method  main queue synchronously, else move your method to ViewdidAppear or ViewWillappear

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()  
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        yourTextField.underlined()
}
}
```

or call like

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     yourTextField.underlined()
}
```